# what would be the formula of $\phi$ in this question?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, several-complex-variables

Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{C}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^2$ be an entire map (i.e, the components of $\phi$ are entire in each variable separately) with $\phi_1$,$\phi_2$ as its components satisfying 
$$|\phi(z,w)|^2 - |(z,w)|^2\leq \operatorname{Im}(\phi_1\overline{\phi_2})-\operatorname{Im}(z\overline{w})$$
Then what would be the formula of $\phi$? Or how does $\phi$ look like?

thanks in advance, I need a hint at least.

Comment: Do you have some additional context? Does this come from a problem in complex dynamics?

Comment: I don't know what is Complex Dynamics. I was checking boundedness of an operator which depends on an analytic map like this.